# Walter Warwick Sawyer: How has reading his works changed your learning or teaching?

Tags: mathematical-pedagogy, self-learning, applied-mathematics

I recently worked my way through Walter Warwick Sawyer's book, *Mathematician's Delight*, which has opened my eyes to Maths. I used to fear maths, feeling I was incapable. Sawyer (among other authors) has a gift for teaching the subject. I now feel much more confident tackling Maths problems, I have a better intuitive understanding of Maths and a renewed interest in it.

There's a nice summary of Sawyer's life and work here: https://plus.maths.org/content/os/latestnews/may-aug08/sawyer/index

Have you had a similar experience after encountering Sawyer's work?

Stephen

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately, this site is not suited for opinion-based questions, and this question is likely to be closed as a result. If you have other questions that should have a definite correct answer, based on teacher experience, training, or research, feel free to ask those in the future.

Comment: The question might be suitable if you ask whether anyone, in their teaching, has incorporated examples/ideas from any of Sawyer's books in class, and to what extent was it helpful?

Comment: I have voted to close this question, as it does not seem to meet the site guidelines.  Per the [help pages](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask): "If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here."  This seems like an invitation to a discussion.

Comment: Stephen, I edited the title so that your question might fit our site better. @XanderHenderson, does that change help? Is there more I could do to make this fit?

Comment: I hadn't heard of him before I read this question, and took the opportunity to take a look into "Mathematician's delight". His explanations are fabulous indeed! This goes right into the list of books I recommend to beginning math students (and in particular to those who plan to become teachers).

Comment: @SueVanHattum Thank you! That’s a much better question.

Comment: @SueVanHattum This isn't a hill I care to die on, but I think that the underlying problem with the question is not that it is looking for opinions, but rather that the question seems to be looking to start a discussion, which is not quite the goal of the SE network.

Comment: I see that, and I see that it's a flaw for se. (Where would he go for that, I wonder.) But it seems worth modifying the question, since Sawyer's work is completely aligned with mese's goals.

Answer (score 16):

No, I was never inspired by him because I had never heard of him before you mentioned it.

---

<sup>Note: My answer is for the original version of the question.  Since then, the question has been edited so my answer is no longer appropriate.</sup>

Comment: So now that it's been a day since you've heard of him have you been inspired? :)

Comment: @Thierry, not yet.  I haven't read his works yet.

Answer (score 7):

I already loved math when I encountered his books. But yes, I was also inspired. ***Mathematician's Delight*** might be the one I put dozens of page markers in, so I could find all the great ideas again. He helped me think about how I might want to teach differently, especially in beginning algebra. I have quite a few of his books. The ones on higher math (like abstract algebra) are fun for me to work through.

[This site](https://www.wwsawyer.org/work-by-sawyer.html) has lists of both his books and articles he wrote.

Thanks for posting this at the beginning of my summer break. I might try to find a few more of his books, and will definitely pull one out again to work on.

Comment: Several of Sawyer's books are freely available at [the internet archive](https://archive.org/search.php?query=subject%3A%22W.+W.+Sawyer%22), more than I would expect (even some that I don't have physical copies of), and thus they might not remain freely available if anyone in authority there happens to pay more attention, something I only noticed 2 days ago when I recommended Sawyer's book **A Concrete Approach to Abstract Algebra** in [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4459613/13130) (question since has been closed, so only viewable by those with sufficient MSE reputation).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I remember vividly my chance encounter at the library with that book of  his! Yes, it had a big impact on me. The idea that mathematics was a real thing in its own right, like music, and not just a school subject, and not just a device to filter people out.